# Can't get typeahead data throughout website

Tags: ruby-on-rails-3, bootstrap-typeahead

I have a rails app where I want to let users use a search box to search other users. The search box is in the navbar at the top but I don't know how to load the data up so that whatever page is loaded from whichever controller, the data will still be up there. Right now I just pass it to the home page via its controller, but typeahead doesn't work on other pages since I don't know how to pass the data.

Is there some way of defining it such that it is always there for the typeahead search box to use?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Define the array of values on an instance variable inside `application_controller.rb`.
All controllers inherit from it, so it would be available everywhere.

EDIT

`application_helper.rb`

```
def populate_typeahead
  ['A', 'B', 'C']
end
```

`view.html.erb`

```
#use populate_typeahead on any place.
```

Comment: I thought of doing it however, just blatantly declaring it there didn't work. do I put it in a method or just putting it in there should work?

Comment: Well, you can put it in a method inside `application_helper.rb` too, and use it on you views. Example on edit.